# Align title with image and add margin between the image and content is not working

Tags: css

I want to achieve a layout like this:

[image]

But its not working properly, Im getting this: http://jsfiddle.net/9cfqjmkb/. The title should be aligned with the top of the image but its not working. Do you know why?

Also I want some margin between the image and the other div with the title and post date, as it is in the image above, but the margin is not working. Do you know why?

HTML

```
<div class="container">


  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-3">
      <div class="bg-custom-light2 p-0">
        <h2 class="font-weight-bold text-custom-blue-dark h5 border-color p-2">Title</h2>
        <ul class="list-group">

          <li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
            <div>
              <h6 class="font-weight-bold text-custom-blue-dark">Test title example for
                example test post</h6>
              <p>post date date</p>
            </div>
            <img class="ml-2" src="https://via.placeholder.com/50" alt="">
          </li>
          <li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
            <div>
              <h6 class="font-weight-bold text-custom-blue-dark">Test title example for
                example test post</h6>
              <p>post date date</p>
            </div>
            <img class="ml-2" src="https://via.placeholder.com/50" alt="">
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

?

```css
.list-group {
  width:300px;
}

.ml-2 {
  align-self:flex-start;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">


  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-3">
      <div class="bg-custom-light2 p-0">
        <h2 class="font-weight-bold text-custom-blue-dark h5 border-color p-2">Title</h2>
        <ul class="list-group">

          <li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
            <div>
              <h6 class="font-weight-bold text-custom-blue-dark">Test title example for
                example test post</h6>
              <p>post date date</p>
            </div>
            <img class="ml-2" src="https://via.placeholder.com/50" alt="">
          </li>
          <li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
            <div>
              <h6 class="font-weight-bold text-custom-blue-dark">Test title example for
                example test post</h6>
              <p>post date date</p>
            </div>
            <img class="ml-2" src="https://via.placeholder.com/50" alt="">
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but like that the background color of the "Title" is not working properly: "http://jsfiddle.net/9cfqjmkb/1/".

Comment: use this `.bg-custom-light2{
  background-color:#e0e0e0;
  width:300px;
}`

Comment: Thanks, is not correct have only the "

.ml-2 {
  align-self:flex-start;
}"? And dont have the ".list-group {
  width:300px;
}"?